# R throw NA on error

Tags: r

Supposing I want to turn the character "6000" into an integer. I could do it with

```
as.integer(6000)
```

However, let's say that the user input was "6***". This gives me an error. How do I convert

```
as.integer(6***)
```

into NA.

Comment: is `6***` a character string?  If so R should turn it to an NA automatically?

Comment: If it is a character, it needs to be in quotes. example:`> as.numeric('6***')
[1] NA`. In your first case, `6000` is already numeric. You'd have to do `as.numeric(as.character(6000))`

Comment: You can't for such input as `*` is a binary operator, a function expecting two arguments one on each side of `*`. Your construct will throw an error from the parser before the function `as.integer()` is even called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would never write `as.integer(6000)` or `as.integer(6***)`.

Instead you would write

```
as.integer("6***")
```

or even more likely

```
as.integer(str)
```

where `str` was some text provided by user input. Perhaps read from a file and so on.

In which case

```
as.integer(str)
```

will indeed return `NA` if `str` is a character string containing `6***`.

```
> str = "6***"
> as.integer(str)
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```